# List in place sorting in Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: sorting, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to sort a list of objects in Jenkins pipelines. I'm getting different results running code below locally or within Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('default'){
            steps {
                script {
                   @NonCPS
                   def nonCpsTest = {
                        def list = [
                            ['CreationDate': '200'],
                            ['CreationDate': '300'],
                            ['CreationDate': '100'],
                       ]

                       def rval = list.sort { it['CreationDate'] }

                       echo "Rval=$rval"
                       echo "List=$list"  
                   }
                   nonCpsTest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this script locally using groovy shell (`groovysh`) result is

```
groovy:000> list = [[ 'CreationDate':200 ], [ 'CreationDate':300 ], [ 'CreationDate':100 ]]
===> [[CreationDate:200], [CreationDate:300], [CreationDate:100]]
groovy:000>  rval = list.sort { it['CreationDate'] }
===> [[CreationDate:100], [CreationDate:200], [CreationDate:300]]
groovy:000> list
===> [[CreationDate:100], [CreationDate:200], [CreationDate:300]]
groovy:000> list == rval
===> true
```

While on the Jenkins server I'm getting following

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (default)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Rval=300
[Pipeline] echo
List=[[CreationDate:200], [CreationDate:300], [CreationDate:100]]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Is Jenkins workflow making list immutable in anyway, or overriding `sort` method, and if so, how to do in place list sorting within the Jenkins pipeline code?

Comment: You should be able to use `rval `, right?

Comment: I'm trying to pull youngest element in the list, as the element with "highest" date. Rval is just for debugging purposes, showing different behaviour in Jenkins and console.

Comment: @toske Your output from Jenkins server points to this part of code `echo "List=$list"` You're displaying initial list that was not sorted (sort does not mutate input list but returns a new sorted one). `rval` holds this new sorted list.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I've updated question to display full output from Jenkins run and console. By default `.sort` method should do in place sort, and return pointer to same array (as you can see from shell out above). However, running in Jenkins this is not the case. If you look above, you'll see that `sort` method returned last item in naturally sorted list, and list wasn't sorted - however example from shell demonstrates that `.sort()` *does* mutate the list.

Comment: @toske Yes, you're right about `.sort` and sorting in place. It's counter-intuitive. What happens when you run `def rval = list.sort(true) { it['CreationDate'] }` to force mutation? You can also double check what is the type of `list` variable when running in Jenkins - auto mutation happens to `List` only.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak running with `def rval = list.sort true, { it['CreationDate'] }` results in identical behaviour. I've also tried using `java.util.Collections.sort()` with no luck.

Comment: @toske One more interesting thing - notice that `rval` displays `300` instead of sorted list. This is very weird. Looks like this issue is still opened - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44924

Comment: Could you please try to do the sorting in the the following way: `def rval = list.sort { e -> e['CreationDate'] }`? Is suppose that there might be mess-up with closures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem that you declared `nonCpsTest` as a variable and it references to closure, so `@NonCPS` does not work in this case

the following variant works fine:

```
@NonCPS
def nonCpsTest() {
    def list = [
        ['CreationDate': '200'],
        ['CreationDate': '300'],
        ['CreationDate': '100'],
    ]
    def rval = list.sort{ it['CreationDate'] }
    echo "Rval=$rval"
    echo "List=$list"  
}

node{
   nonCpsTest()
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked with bit of modification to make it declarative pipeline code - https://gist.github.com/toshke/c22e5b924f061cb067ae895accb0da32